# Where can I find a drawing of the physical structure of a MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL but want to learn more about it.  I know Oracle and Rdb quite well.  Can you show me where I can locate some type of drawing of the physical structure of a MySQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Below screenshot shows MySQL architecture at detailed level.

[image: MySQL Architecture]

Comment: Perhaps you can add a refernce/link?